# Can Objective C determine the caller object reference at runtime (reflection)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, reflection

As far as I understand Objective C is a much more dynamic language than C# or Java. In C# you can only know the class of the caller object (using stacktrace) but not the instance reference of the caller itself.

Is Objective C more capable for this ?

Update: I looked the other post here [How can I determine the "caller" of my method in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970354/how-can-i-determine-the-caller-of-my-method-in-objective-c). As far as I understand it only gives Class Name. I insist that I'm not interested only by class name but by getting a ref to the caller **instance** itself.

Comment: Rather than reiterate what you want, please explain what it is you are trying to do. Getting the callee instance is probably not possible in Objective-C, but your higher-level problem may be solvable in a different way.

Answer (score 6):

This has already been answered here:

[How can I determine the "caller" of my method in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970354/how-can-i-determine-the-caller-of-my-method-in-objective-c)

The answer's not particularly pretty though. It looks like there's no simple, reliable way to do it other than hunting through the stack, which might be OS version or platform dependent.

Why exactly did you want to do this? Perhaps there's another solution to your problem.

Comment: I looked the other post. As far as I understand it only gives Class Name. I'm not interested only by class name but by the instance itself.

Comment: Then it is probably not possible. As others have said, the Objective-C message sending system revolves around the objc_msgSend() function, which takes a callee and selector parameter, but not the caller.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you can't get even the class of the caller. All method calls in Objective-C are routed through `objc_msgSend()`, which takes the receiver, a selector and the parameters of the method as parameters.

The receiver will be `self` and the selector `_cmd`. The caller isn't involved in the method call. You can only go back the stack trace in order to know where the method has been called.

Comment: stack trace does only give class name not instance ref as far as I can read http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/c-stack-traces-with-gcc/

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be a start: `NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);`.

Although, I think you need to see this thread first :
[How to find out who called a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method/1794051#1794051)

Also [NSThread Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/callStackSymbols) :)

Comment: Would this really give object reference of the caller and not only its class name ?